# python passing array structure to view as json

Tags: jquery, python, arrays, json, plugins

```
Python API returns the following data when requested::

x_values = [
  [0,'10:00:00 AM'],
  [1,'10:00:10 AM'],
  [2,'10:00:10 AM'],
  [3,'10:00:20 AM']
]
y_values = [
  [0,3],
  [1,0],
  [2,3],
  [3,1]
]
data = {
  "x":x_values,
  "y":y_values
}
self.send_json(data)
```

This is api using Python 2.7.9.  And the following is the jquery script.

```
$('.flot-graph').each(function() {
    var graph_drawing_area = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/get/data', // call the api
        success: function(data){
            var y = JSON.stringify(data['y']);
            var x = JSON.stringify(data['x']);
            var graph_data = [
                {
                    data: y
                }    
            ];
            var options = {
                xaxis: {
                    ticks:x
                }
            };
            return $.plot(graph_drawing_area, graph_data, options); 
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
    });

});
```

This is supposed to draw charts on divs with class name 'flot-graph'. The problem I'm having now is that I need to regenerate array structures exactly the same as in python. In other words, the jquery script must look something like

```
success: function(data){
...
    var graph_data = [{
        //note that y is decoded and replaced as array format
        data: [
           [0,3],
           [1,0],
           [2,3],
           [3,1]
        ]
    }];
    var options = {
        //note that x is decoded and replaced as array format
        xaxis: {
            ticks:[
               [0,'10:00:00 AM'],
               [1,'10:00:10 AM'],
               [2,'10:00:10 AM'],
               [3,'10:00:20 AM']
            ]
        }
    };
    return $.plot(graph_drawing_area, graph_data, options); 
},
.......
```

I tried using JSON.stringify but it seems like not regenerating the array back. Also JSON.parse() didn't give me what I want but bunch of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u" error - I assume return value after parsing is not an appropriate option here.

How can I fix this?  If my approach is not the best, what is more appropriate in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: how stupid... I didn't need to parse at all.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to parse it at all... how stupid :'(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Literally, I didn't need to parse it at all.  Data variable itself was already ready to be used. Accessing values via data['x] ,  data['y'] solved all the issues.